# What does the naming-strategy-map tag mean in IntelliJ config?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm working on a project in IDEA Ultimate, and it keeps inserting a `<naming-strategy-map />` tag into the iml file. When I manually remove the tag it gets reinserted again. What does it mean? I tried googling it but I can't seem to find anything.

Here is the context:

[image]

Comment: Most probably it has something to do with the JPA support - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-persistence-tool-window.html#assign_naming_strategy. However, why does this bother you?

Comment: @ThomasKläger I'm just wondering if it's some serious change that I may not want to push to the repository for all the other developers.

Comment: I think it is a Intellij configuration. I never commit this file for the same reason.